# Read and transform data from textFile in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using scala, I have a `case class Point(x: Double = 0, y: Double = 0)` and I am reading a textFile `val data = sc.textFile("Dataset.txt").flatMap(line => line.split(","))` and the data is in the following format(each diferrent value is separated by newline in the file):

> 133.559,244.112
>
> 88.242,100.222

I want the key to be of type Point but after the split the numbers get separated and I don't know how to merge every two of them together to form a Point Key in the RDD. Maybe there is a way to transform it without splitting?

Thanks

Comment: do you want the values to be of type `Point` class ?

Comment: I want the two values of each line to be of type Point where for example 133.559 = x and 244.112 = y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not flatMap :

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    "133.559,244.112","88.242,100.222"
  ))

  val result: RDD[Point] = rdd.map{ e =>
    val Array(x,y) = e.split(",").map(_.toDouble)
    Point(x,y)
  }
```

Comment: I just noticed that this returns Array[Point] and not Point[], am i right? For example if i want to print one Point i have to do ``PointRDD.take(1) foreach println ``.

Comment: Emil, Point[] is the java notation for Array[Point] isn't it ?

Comment: Can i transform it to just Point? because doing ``val a = PointRDD.take(1)(0)`` seems a little off to me. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: In the current dataset you had two points. If you're only interested in getting one point, you can do something like rdd.take(1).map{ e =>... /* see code above */ }.headOption (if you're not sure to always have data, to get an Option[Point], or just .head to have the first Point).

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain correctly. By point I mean the pair of numbers in each line. Both numbers create a Point(x,y). I want to use those points in a Quadtree.